# Importing 143 MB JSON file to MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am importing a JSON file with 150 MB data 
as

```
[{
    "ts" : "1424514943000",
    "val" : 68,
},
{
"ts" : "1424514973000",
    "val" : 83,
},
.
.
.
]
```

in js file, I am using JSONStream.parse

```
const dataStreamFromFile = fs.createReadStream(`./../backend/upload/THERM0001.json`);
        dataStreamFromFile.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*')).on('data', async (chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk)
            await new dataImport(chunk).save();
            res.send('done')
        });
```

The above code is giving an error after importing 450 records as a javascript heap out of memory.
I tried using JSONStream.parse('*.*.*') but it gives me

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out
```

My main objective is to import JSON file with size 150MB to mongoDB

Comment: Is the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html) tool an option?

Comment: No, it has to be through node.js

Comment: If you get the error from the write itself and smaller writes work, increase connection timeout.